# Getting Jest errors - TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I am working in an Expo project and having an issue in which all of the Jest tests are failing due to a `TypeError`:

```
> Test run started at 5/2/2023, 12:02:30 PM <

 FAIL  app/utils/story-building-utils/getCurrentWeek.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/utils/brainstorm-utils/__tests__/slugify.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/models/personas/personas.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/models/brainstorms/brainstorms.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/models/wwxd/wwxd.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  test/i18n.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/api/Persona.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/services/api/api-problem.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/utils/storage/storage.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/models/story-building/story-building.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/utils/brainstorm-utils/__tests__/shuffleArray.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/utils/brainstorm-utils/__tests__/parseParams.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/hooks/useGetBrainstormData/getBrainstormReducer.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/models/auth/auth.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/utils/brainstorm-utils/__tests__/makeTitle.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/utils/brainstorm-utils/createUniqueId.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

 FAIL  app/utils/persona-utils/createUniqueId.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: performance

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:407:20)

Test Suites: 17 failed, 17 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.061 s
Ran all test suites.

> Test run finished at 5/2/2023, 12:02:37 PM <
```

It seems as if this problem started occurring after I upgraded from Expo 44 to 48. I have tried to make sure that my package versions are correct for Expo 48 but I continue to have this problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: it happened to me after I added `'testEnvironment': "jsdom"` in the test.config.js. removing it solved it problem.

Comment: Although this worked for me, it might remove some of the jest functionality that is needed when testing a dom-related project

Answer (score 7):

the node LTS version 18.16.0 is failing, I've downgraded to 18.12 everything is green again ✅

Comment: Upgrading node to 18.7.1 works fine too

Answer (score 4):

I am using react-native v0.71.8, and patched (using `patch-package`) the file `node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js` to fix the errorring lines:

```js
--- a/node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js
@@ -17,12 +17,11 @@ jest.requireActual('@react-native/polyfills/error-guard');
 
 global.__DEV__ = true;
 
-global.performance = {
-  now: jest.fn(Date.now),
-};
+global.performance ??= {};
+global.performance.now = jest.fn(Date.now);
 
 global.regeneratorRuntime = jest.requireActual('regenerator-runtime/runtime');
-global.window = global;
+global.window ??= global;
 
 global.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback) {
   return setTimeout(callback, 0);
```

Essentially all I did was change two assignments (`=`) to nullish coalescing assignments (`??=`), where they will only set the variable if the current value is `null` or `undefined`.

With this patch I was able to use node 18.16 without issue.

Comment: For clarity, the file name used for this patch: `patches/react-native+0.71.8.patch`

Answer (score 1):

The patch answer from Goeff worked for me. However, I had to make a small changes for my react-native version. I am using node v18.16 react-native 0.72.5

Here the updated version of the patch. On `patches/react-native+0.72.5.patch`

```
--- a/node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js
@@ -17,12 +17,11 @@ jest.requireActual('@react-native/polyfills/error-guard');

 global.__DEV__ = true;

-global.performance = {
-  now: jest.fn(Date.now),
-};
+global.performance ??= {};
+global.performance.now = jest.fn(Date.now);

 global.regeneratorRuntime = jest.requireActual('regenerator-runtime/runtime');
-global.window = global;
+global.window ??= global;

 global.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback) {
   return setTimeout(() => callback(jest.now()), 0);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).